# Sum operator and HashMap object as the result

Tags: java, jpql

I have created a JPQL like this:
select sum(c.field1) field1, sum(c.field2) field2, sum(c.field3) field3 from class c

Now there are three problems:
1) I didn't find anywhere if I can use the synthax sum(c.field1) field1;
2) I didn't find anywhere if an aggregate query can have many fields;
3) when I try to execute this query the compiler return a Vector! The strangething is that I can't define the type of fields that will return because its are different (Long, Double and BigInteger) and If I try to return the values of the query it returns:
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@f7b046]

this is the code:

```
         public Vector sumFilteredString(Class2 c2) {
            String query="select sum(c1.field1) field1, sum(c1.field2) field2, sum(c1.field3) field3, sum(c1.field4) field4, sum(c1.field5) field5 from Class1 c1 WHERE c1.idClass2=c2.id";

                Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);

                return (Vector)q.getResultList();
    }
```

I try to use Vector because for me it's not important if I retrieve these values using HashMap.get("field name") or Vector.get(position) so if your solution consist to retrieve a Vector for me it is the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29). The method `getResultList()` returns a `List`. you can't assume that the returned list is a `Vector`. And there's a a very good chance that it won't be a Vector since nobody uses Vector anymore since JDK 1.2.

Your method should return a `List`, not a `Vector`.

Each row of the returned List is an `Object[]`. That's defined by the JPA spec. And each cell element of the row is an object corresponding to the type of the field in your mapping. AFAIK, when you sum a field defined as a Long, you'll get a Long as result. If you sum a field defined as a BigDecimal, you'll get a BigDecimal.

`[[Ljava.lang.Object;@f7b046]` is the result of calling `toString()` on the returned list. All it tells you is that the list contains a single object, whose `toString()` is `[Ljava.lang.Object;@f7b046`. This means that the object is an array of objects, and that the hashCode of the array is `f7b046`.

Comment: @ jb Nizet : Thank you for your answer, yes I know that the vector is obsolete but, as I said, the compiler returned an error that told that the Vector could be not cast into a HashMap... Now the problem is Likely the same, there is something that I can do for retrieve some thing of different from a List that contains 5 Object arrays that contain a single value? Something like a List that contains directly the five fields?

Comment: If your query returns a single row, then use `Query.getSingleResult()`, and you'll have your `Object[]` array directly. Or just use `list.get(0)` to get the first (and unique) `Object[]` from the list.